# cascading drop-down list in mvc 4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I created cascading drop-down list as shown in the picture

here the view

[image]

here the cshtml code snippet

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HEI_ID)
         @Html.Label("*", new { id="star" , @class = "requiredFiledCol" })               
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HEI_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.UniversityList_New, "Select University / Institute", new {id="University", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HEI_ID)
    </div>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COL_ID)
        @Html.Label("*", new { id="star" , @class = "requiredFiledCol" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.COL_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.FacultyList_New, "Select College", new {id="College", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COL_ID)
    </div>
    </div>


  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DEP_ID)
        @Html.Label("*", new { id="star" , @class = "requiredFiledCol" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DEP_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentList_New, "Select Department", new { id="Department" , @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DEP_ID)
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is jquery code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $("#University").change(function () {
        $("#College").empty();
        $("#Department").empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetColleges")', // we are calling json method
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { uni_id: $("#University").val() },
            success: function (Colleges) {

                $.each(Colleges, function (i, state) {

                    $("#College").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');
                }); 
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });

        return false;
    })

    $("#College").change(function () {
        $("#Department").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDepartments")', // we are calling json method
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { col_id: $("#College").val() },
            success: function (Departments) {

                $.each(Departments, function (i, state) {


                    $("#Department").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');
                }); 
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
                return false;
            })


});
```

But in last dropdown (department drop down) its not populate , how can I overcome this

this is the action methods related to this module

```
 public JsonResult GetColleges(string uni_id)
    {
        var Colleges = from college in db.Colleges
                       where college.HEI_ID == uni_id & college.Status == true
                       select college;


        //List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();

        return Json(new SelectList(Colleges.ToList(), "College_ID", "College_Name"));
    }

    public JsonResult GetDepartments(string col_id)
    {
        var Departments = from department in db.Departments
                          where department.College_ID == col_id & department.Status == true
                          select department;


        //List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();

        return Json(new SelectList(Departments.ToList(), "Department_ID", "Name_of_Department"));
    }
```

Comment: What error are your getting exactly ?

Comment: last drop down(department drop down) not populate

Comment: You need to show the source code of controller action `GetDepartments`.

Comment: try using `on('change',function(){});`

Comment: `on('change',function(){});` populate irrelevant data also

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and it is working for me fine but not when you have only one item returned and populated in the **College** dropdown. That is because `change()` will not be fired if you have only 1 item and you select that. So to avoid what you can do is when cascade load data in dropdown add a option label so that user has to select a valid option and change gets fired and thus, Department dropdown get loaded with data. So your College change can look like this:

```
$("#College").change(function () {
    $("#Department").empty();

    //If option label was selected then do not send request
    if ($("#College").val() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDepartments")', 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            col_id: $("#College").val()
        },
        success: function (Departments) {

            //Add option label as the first element (selected by default)
            $("#Department").append('<option value="0">-SELECT COLLEGE-</option>');

            $.each(Departments, function (i, state) {
                $("#Department").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

NOTE: Changes indicated with comment above code